# How To Get Laravel Controller Method Name & Method Type Automatically

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Basically I'm calling an event every time a Controller method runs:

```
public function destroy(User $user)
{
   event(new AdminActivity('admin.users.destroy',class_basename(Route::current()->controller),'destroy','DELETE'));

   ...
}
```

In fact it is saving this information:

```
event(new AdminActivity(ROUTE_NAME,CONTROLLER_NAME,CONTROLLER_METHOD_NAME,CONTROLLER_METHOD_TYPE));
```

Now instead of passing parameters manually, I want to pass the required parameters automatically.

So I need to get **route name**, **controller method name** and **controller method type** auto (just like the `class_basename(Route::current()->controller)` which returns the controller name).

So how can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `Route::current()` to the event and then get your required information from the object of `\Illuminate\Routing\Route`

```php
public function destroy(User $user)
{
   event(new AdminActivity(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::current()));

   ...
}
```

Then, in your `AdminActivity` event class

```php
class AdminActivity
{
    public function __construct(\Illuminate\Routing\Route $route)
    {
        $controllerClass  = class_basename($route->getController());
        $controllerMethod = $route->getActionMethod();
        $routeName        = $route->getAction('as');
        $methods          = $route->methods();
    }
}
```

**Notice**: return type of `$route->methods()` is an array that contains all valid request methods (GET, HEAD, POST, ...)

Comment: Do you suggest doing this thing with Events or Observers?

Comment: Using listeners or defining an observer for an entity are just two different approaches for achieving a same logic. It mostly depends on your preferences rather on a de facto.